# How do you add multiple arguments from different functions into one function containing all the parameters?

Tags: javascript

**Is this possible in JavaScript**

I am curious, if I set up three parameters in one function, can I pass the arguments independently in three different functions?

For example, if I created a function that calculates three parameters like the one below, can I then just pass an argument for each of these parameters x, y and z in three different functions.

I understand the example code is not a very good example but its the only way I could think up a explanation.

**Main function**

```
function mathsCal(x, y, z) {
return (x * y) - z;
}
```

**The three independent functions**

```
function one(x) {
return x = 23;
}

function two(y) {
return x = 19;
}

function three(z) {
return x = 45;
}
```

Comment: what you need is to add the results from 3 different functions and add them into a 4th one as parameters am I right? or you want to run multiple functions inside a single one containing all parameters?

Comment: Can you provide a code example, please.

Comment: Do you mean something like `sumNum(num1(), num2(), num3())`?

Comment: this is an example of 2 functions inside a 3rd one https://jsfiddle.net/kenpy/L1ra8pfw/29/
call the function by pressing a button

Comment: @RobMc is that what you need?

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. You are calling a function that needs 3 parameters inside a function where it's result is equivalent to only one of the parameters needed

Comment: Chris G - Thank you for your answer. I will see if that works with a project I am doing at home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this for example you have your 3 functions, each of them receive 1 parameter

```
function num1(param) {
  //your code for num1, return a value
  return param
}


function num2(param) {
  //your code for num2, return a value
  return param
}


function num3(param) {
  //your code for num3, return a value
  return param
}
```

Then you can call them all inside single function that will receive all 3 parameters needed for `num1`, `num2` and `num3`

```
function sumNum(x, y, z) {
    var value1 = num1(x);
    var value2 = num1(y);
    var value3 = num1(z);
    return (value1 * value2) + value3;
}
```

Then call your function with the needed parameters

```
var result = sumNum(1,2,3)
console.log(result);//your output = 5
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris G - Your advice has been most helpful and it will help me further my understanding of functions within Javascript and how they interact with other snippets of code.

Answer (score 0):

Without using JQuery and using the code I got from user "Chris G", I believe this is the best answer to my question.  Please leave comments if I have written this wrong so I can correct it.

```
<button id= "btn">Get Answer</button>
```

```
var numVal1 = 2;
var numVal2 = 6;
var numVal3 = 9;

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
funcPara(numVal1, numVal2, numVal3);
})

function funcPara(x, y, z) {

num1(x);
num2(y);
num3(z);

}


function num1(para) {

console.log(`num1 = ${para}`);  

}


function num2(para) {

console.log(`num2 = ${para}`);

}


function num3(para) {

console.log(`num3 = ${para}`);

}
```

Comment: a few things are wrong in your code, give me a min I will show you whats wrong

Comment: `1st` is always better to give your button an id and use that to play with that element `<button id="id_button">Get Answer</button>`
`2nd` You declared `var numval2=6 ` first then you declared `numval2 =9` for the same variable, I'm assumming you wanted to declare `var numval3=9` so that you have 3 different variables
`3rd` you already declared what your function does here`function funcPara(x, y, z) {` then you don't need to add the word `function` again inside your `addEventListener("click"` instead you only need to call your function like this `funcPara(numVal1, numval2, numval3);`

Comment: and `last` instead of query selector since you button has an id now you can use this instead `document.getElementById('id_button').addEventListener("click", function() {`

This is how your code looks with a few changes https://jsfiddle.net/kenpy/7kfjzvyh/22/

Comment: Understood, still learning and making code typing errors, lol

Comment: Hopefully, I have corrected everything as instructed by Chris G so as not to mislead any viewers.

Comment: just 1 more mistake on your new code lol. `numval2` is not equal to  `numVal2` with Capital V, same with `numval3`
You sending the wrong variable to your function `funcPara(numVal1, numVal2, numVal3);`
Fix that and your code works like a charm, gl man